# IdentityManager does not get all claims

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, identitymanager

I have an IdentityServer set up with only one hybrid-flow client that sets **"all_claims"** for **AllowedScopes**. On another computer I have an MVC app that connects to IdSvr to log-in the user. It also sets a `/admin` binding for IdMgr. I can log-in to the main app and to IdMgr with no problem. Also in the main app after user logs-in I get all the claims as expected, but not in IdMgr.

I'm trying to add some custom logic in IdMgr based on claims. But when I get `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in any IdMgr controller, it is empty! All I get is a **ClaimsPrincipal** object with only role claims. It also has one **ClaimsIdentity** object with the following properties:

```
AuthenticationType: "Bearer"
IsAuthenticated: true
NameClaimType: "name"
RoleClaimType: "role"
```

and everything else is null. There's not even a name or Id for the user. Why is this, and how can I get all claims in IdentityManager?

To reproduce this, just inspect `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in the `GetUsersAsync` method in [`UsersController`](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Core/Api/Controllers/UserController.cs).

*Link to this [issue](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/issues/216) on GitHub*

Answer (score 0):

Try **IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true** in identity manager scope

```
            new Scope{
                Name = IdentityManager.Constants.IdMgrScope,
                DisplayName = "IdentityManager",
                Description = "Authorization for IdentityManager",
                Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true
```

Comment: Should I put that in client side code (IdMgr) or in IdSvr? The only place I see in IdMgr that sets the scope is [this](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/ExternalBearerTokenConfiguration.cs#L32) in which the scope is string only.

Comment: This should be configured in Idsrv Scope configuration. Sorry but it looks like it won't answer your question. only role and name claims are present in the principal as Brock commented above. It appeared to me at first time it resolved the problem of empty currentprincipal. But I might have missed something else.

Answer (score -1):

If you want custom claims for IdMgr, then I'd suggest you do claims transformation in your pipeline.

Comment: I do, but the `ClaimsPrincipal` that I get in any IdMgr action method does not include the custom user claims to be transformed. Looks like IdMgr is overwriting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` with a filtered object.

Comment: IdMgr is only accepting name and role claims from the external Idp.